# Getting values of a particular row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which prints the values in a datatable.

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $val) {
?>
<input class="example" type="checkbox" value="yes" id="example" name="example"><?php echo $val->id; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Now I want to send the value to the server when the checkbox is checked. I have the following code for the same, however I'm confused on how I can get the ID of the row which is echoed by PHP.

```
$(".example").change(function() {
var value = $('.example').attr('value');
console.log(value);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want the values of the checked checkboxes?

Comment: @ImmortalDude Yes. I want the value as well as the value of echoed variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an another attribute to the checkbox like :

```
<input type="checkbox" data-id="<?php echo val->id ?>">
```

Then your code will :

```
$(".example").change(function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).data("id")
        console.log(value);
        console.log(id);
    }
});
```

Comment: use `$(this).attr('data-id')` over `$(this).data('id')`.. using `attr` is faster and also `.data()` will cache your results which is not required in this scenario.